# TypeScript: why is a number assignable to a reference of type Object?

Tags: typescript, primitive, coercion, subtyping

Why is this legal TypeScript?

```
var x: number = 5
var y: Object = x
```

Surely a number is not an `Object`. One might suspect that x is implicitly coerced (auto-boxed) to an object, but no:

```
if (!(y instanceof Object)) {
   console.log(typeof y)
}
```

prints

```
number
```

For the record:

```
$ tsc --version
Version 1.8.10
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on **structural** subtyping, not nominal typing. That said, consider the two following interface definitions:

```
interface IFoo { X: number }
interface IBar { X: number; Y: number }
```

Does `IBar` extend `IFoo`? No.

But is `IFoo` compatible with `IBar`? Yes.

The members of `IFoo` are a subset of `IBar` members, thus you can assign any `IBar` to `IFoo`. But it doesn't work the other way around:

```
var x: IFoo;
var y: IBar;

x = y // all good
y = x // type error, x has no Y member
```

This way in Typescript all types are compatible with `Object` if you think of it as the empty interface. This way you can pass any valid typescript value to functions accepting `Object` and play well with the way Javascript libs are written.

I suggest reading [Type Compatibility](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) in docs and the last paragraph about *Subtype vs Assignment*.

Comment: Ok, that's the essentially the explanation I was anticipating (after noticing that I could also assign a bool to an empty interface I defined called Bool, which is isomorphic to Object). I understand structural vs. nominal, but hadn't expected it to apply to non-reference types. I guess this is only sound to the extent to which Object really has an empty interface (given that there are probably things I can do to an object that I can't do to a number or primitive string).

Comment: I'm happy with the explanation, so I've accepted the answer. Turns out I was getting bitten not because number < Object (which seems OK, modulo my caveat above), but because subtyping of function types seems borked. Here's a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39569016.

Comment: I guess here's a sense in which number < Object is unsound: it breaks the upward-closure of instanceof. In other words, X < Y and x instanceof X should imply x instanceof Y.

Comment: I really understand your objections (can't disagree that TypeScript's type system presents some unsound cases), but usually the answer is (for good or bad), that it enables patterns common in Javascript :) Check also [function bivariance](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#function-parameter-bivariance) in docs.