# Typescript Array accepts wrong type

Tags: arrays, typescript

I would expect the following code to fail to transpile, as B should not be a valid type for array.push. What am I missing?

```
class A {};
class B {};
const arr: A[] = [];
arr.push(new B());
```

Comment: `A` and `B` are structurally the same, that's why TypeScript accepts it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html

Comment: Here's a helpful answer on S.O. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39562956/831878

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49135069/typescript-generic-type-check-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TypeScript uses structural compatibility to determine type compatibility. The classes are structurally compatible since they have the same properties (empty object).

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html